# Trying to create a custom post blog for an archive section at my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, posts

any help would be amazing. I am working on a custom theme for WordPress and trying to create a new section in my dashboard to add custom posts for an archive. and is not working. It seems to be all fine.

This is my custom file, it's quite basic. Any help would be amazing

```
<?php
/**
 * mothertongues functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package mothertongues
 */

if ( ! defined( '_S_VERSION' ) ) {
    // Replace the version number of the theme on each release.
    define( '_S_VERSION', '1.0.0' );
}

/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */
function mothertongues_setup() {
    /*
        * Make theme available for translation.
        * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
        * If you're building a theme based on mothertongues, use a find and replace
        * to change 'mothertongues' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
        */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'mothertongues', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /*
        * Let WordPress manage the document title.
        * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
        * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
        * provide it for us.
        */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    /*
        * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
        *
        * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
        */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'mothertongues' ),
        )
    );

    /*
        * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
        * to output valid HTML5.
        */
    add_theme_support(
        'html5',
        array(
            'search-form',
            'comment-form',
            'comment-list',
            'gallery',
            'caption',
            'style',
            'script',
        )
    );

    // Set up the WordPress core custom background feature.
    add_theme_support(
        'custom-background',
        apply_filters(
            'mothertongues_custom_background_args',
            array(
                'default-color' => 'ffffff',
                'default-image' => '',
            )
        )
    );

    // Add theme support for selective refresh for widgets.
    add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );

    /**
     * Add support for core custom logo.
     *
     * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo
     */
    add_theme_support(
        'custom-logo',
        array(
            'height'      => 250,
            'width'       => 250,
            'flex-width'  => true,
            'flex-height' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mothertongues_setup' );

/**
 * Set the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 *
 * Priority 0 to make it available to lower priority callbacks.
 *
 * @global int $content_width
 */
function mothertongues_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'mothertongues_content_width', 640 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mothertongues_content_width', 0 );

/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/#registering-a-sidebar
 */
function mothertongues_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'mothertongues' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'mothertongues' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mothertongues_widgets_init' );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function mothertongues_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mothertongues-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_style_add_data( 'mothertongues-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mothertongues-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mothertongues_scripts' );

/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Functions which enhance the theme by hooking into WordPress.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-functions.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
if ( defined( 'JETPACK__VERSION' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
}

// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Intros', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Intro', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'public'                => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'intro', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

And this is the specific bit where I try to set up the custom posts

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Intros', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Intro', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'public'                => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'intro', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

But the new menu item in my dashboard is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask on the proper community website https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it. Did that.